# Foursquare venues/search gives error 400

Tags: android, foursquare

I am trying to use one of the userless APIs to get a list of venues from Foursquare.  Here's my URL:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&v=20140303

Not sure why I get a 400 - here's my response:

{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}

Please help.  Thanks.
Ron

Comment: "errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. might give a hint ?

Comment: Your client_id and/or client_secret must be incorrect. You can test the call at [hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) to make sure those are correct. If that works then its your code so it'd be helpful to post that.

Comment: The point is, I shouldn't have to have access creds.  My client id and secret should be enough.  When I use my clientId/secret on the Foursquare "try it out" page, it does work, but it adds the oauth param automatically for me.  Not sure why.  My client_id/secret are correct - I cut and pasted them from foursquare.

Comment: Sorry, not the "try it out" page.  I meant "API Explorer" page.

Comment: @Ron - I'm still getting the same error though I have correct Client Id and secrete,.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - one should be careful when cutting/pasting their client id/secret.  Geez.